# Rails 4 x AJAX: partial not reloading on click with remote: true

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 app, I have a `Post` model with a custom `approval` attribute.

I am trying to update this custom `approval` attribute from the Posts#Show page when the user clicks on one of three particular links set with `remote: true`.

The goal is to reload only the partial displaying the content of this attribute, and not the entire page.

Here is my `Post` `show.html.erb` view:

```
<div id="post_show_approval">
  <%= render 'approval' %>
</div>
```

And here is my _approval.html.erb partial, located in the `app/views/posts` folder:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <% if @post.approval == "ok" %>
      <span class="ok_green">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
          Post Approved
      </span>
    <% else %>
      <span class="approval_blue" %>
        <%= link_to post_path(:id => @post.id, "post[approval]" => "ok"), :class => "post_appoval_link", remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
          Approve this post
      </span>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </li>
  <li id="post_show_require_edits">
    <% if @post.approval == "edit" %>
      <span class="edit_yellow">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span>
          This post requires edits
      </span>
    <% else %>
        <span class="approval_blue" %>
          <%= link_to post_path(:id => @post.id, "post[approval]" => "edit"), :class => "post_appoval_link", remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span>
          Require edits for this post
        </span>
          <% end %>
    <% end %>
    </li>
  <li id="post_show_to_be_deleted">
    <% if @post.approval == "remove" %>
        <span class="remove_red">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
          This post needs to be deleted
        </span>
      <% else %>
        <span class="approval_blue" %>
          <%= link_to post_path(:id => @post.id, "post[approval]" => "remove"), :class => "post_appoval_link", remote: true, :method => :patch do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            Mark this post as to be deleted
          <% end %>
        </span>
      <% end %>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, all the links with the `post_approval_link` class are set with `remote: true`.

Then, I have updated my `PostsController` as follows:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.update(post_params)
      format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And I have created an `update.js.erb` file in the `app/views/posts` folder:

```
$('#post_show_approval').reload(true);
```

—————

**UPDATE**: as alternatives to the above line, I also tried

```
$('#post_show_approval').hide().show();
```

and

```
$('#post_show_approval').toggle().toggle();
```

But none of these seem to work.

—————

**UPDATE 2**: here is another thing I tried:

```
$('#post_show_approval').load('<%= j render "approval" %>');
```

But it is not working either.

—————

**UPDATE 3**: when I try only

```
$('#post_show_approval').hide();
```

or

```
$('#post_show_approval').toggle();
```

The div does disappear.

But I still did not find a way to make it reappear with its content updated.

—————

**UPDATE 4**: also, when I use:

```
$('#post_show_approval').append('<%= j render(partial: "approval") %>');
```

The `approval` partial does load with its updated content... the initial content does not disappear, so every time we click on one of the links, a new line of content stacks up.

—————

However, when I click on one of the three links with the `post_approval_link` class, the `appoval` attribute of the post is actually updated to the correct value, but the `#post_show_approval` div is not reloaded and I need to refresh the page to see the actual changes.

What am I missing in the implementation of this AJAX feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was not using the right JavaScript method.

With:

```
$('#post_show_approval').html('<%= j render(partial: "approval") %>');
```

It is now working like a charm.